# How to run an If-Then-Else statement which includes a qry against a table on another sql instance, if table does not exists?

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm trying to only execute a sql statement against a database on another instance if the table exists in that database. I've done this repeatedly when querying while the qry window is connected to the instance where the database exists. But, this approach does not work when the qry window is connected to another instance. Note: I am connected to both instances in the object explorer.

The following code is run dynamically (EXEC @strSQL). The table does not exist, and I'm expected the printed response 'NOT EXISTS'.

```
> IF EXISTS (
>                   SELECT 1
>                   FROM [SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].sys.tables
>                   WHERE name = N'SomeTableThatDoesNotExist' 
>                       AND type = 'U'
>           )   
>   BEGIN       
>       PRINT 'EXISTS'      
>       SELECT *        
>       FROM [SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTableThatDoesNotExist]    
>   END                         
>   ELSE
>       PRINT 'NOT EXISTS'
```

Dynamic Version as requested:

```
>   DECLARE @strSQL     VARCHAR(MAX)

>   SET @strSQL = '             
>       IF (OBJECT_ID(''[SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTableThatDoesNotExist]'') IS NOT NULL)
>       BEGIN
>           PRINT ''IS NOT NULL''
>           SELECT *
>           FROM [SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTableThatDoesNotExist];
>       END 
>       ELSE
>           PRINT ''IS NULL''
>       ';

>   BEGIN TRY
>       BEGIN TRANSACTION;
>           EXEC(@strSQL);
>       COMMIT TRANSACTION;
>   END TRY
>   BEGIN CATCH
>       EXECUTE up_tidydata_GetErrorInfo;
>   END CATCH
```

Dynamic Inside Dynamic version 1

```
>   
>   IF (OBJECT_ID('[SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTableThatDoesNotExist') IS NOT NULL)
>       DECLARE @strSQLqry VARCHAR(MAX)
>       SET @strSQLqry = '
>           DECLARE @strSQLinside AS VARCHAR(MAX)
>           SET @strSQLinside = ''SELECT * FROM [SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTableThatDoesNotExist];''
>           EXEC(@strSQLinside);
>           ';
>   EXEC(@strSQLqry)
```

Dynamic Inside Dynamic version 2

```
>   
>   DECLARE @strSQL     VARCHAR(MAX)
>   SET @strSQL = ' 
>       IF (OBJECT_ID(''[SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTableThatDoesNotExist]'') IS NOT NULL)
>       DECLARE @strSQLqry VARCHAR(MAX)
>       SET @strSQLqry = ''
>           DECLARE @strSQLinside AS VARCHAR(MAX)
>           SET @strSQLinside = ''''SELECT * FROM [SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTableThatDoesNotExist];''''
>           EXEC(@strSQLinside);
>           '';
>       EXEC(@strSQLqry)
>       ';
>   EXEC(@strSQL)
```

When it runs on the instance where the database exists, it works as expected. Meaning skips the Begin...End and goes to the ELSE section.

However, when it runs on another instance, it errors, saying the table does not exist in the database (which is why the conditional if-then-else is used). When I qry a table that does exist in the database on the other instance, the expected response is received, 'EXISTS'. So, it seems that the both the THEN statements and ELSE statements must be valid when running on another instance.

I thought to confirm this by commenting out the FROM line. When I ran that on the instance where the database exists, the response is 'NOT EXISTS' as expected (meaning it ignored the BEGIN...END).

However, when I ran that while connected to another instance, this produced an error 'must specify table to select from.'

Note, I've attempted with variants of checking for the table (If EXISTS, IF OBJECT_ID...IS NOT NULL)

Comment: My suggestion would have been dynamic sql, but you say that is what you are using.   Can you expand your code to include the part that creates the dynamic sql string and executes it?

Comment: The dynamic version, also showing the OBJECT_ID approach, is being  included in original message

Comment: A problem with your dynamic-within-dynamic attempts:   you need to use BEGIN END blocks with the IF statements.  Otherwise, only the first statement after the IF hinges on the IF being true.  All the rest will get executed.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the problem is that you are running your whole example query in one dynamic context.

I think if you try it this way, it will work:

```
IF EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM [SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].sys.tables
                  WHERE name = N'SomeTableThatDoesNotExist' 
                      AND type = 'U'
          )  
      BEGIN       
      PRINT 'EXISTS';
      DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = '
        SELECT *        
        FROM [SomeInstance].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[SomeTableThatDoesNotExist]
      ';
      EXEC(@sql);
      END                            
      ELSE
           PRINT 'NOT EXISTS'
```

And if you have to make the whole thing dynamic for some other reason, then I think you will still have success with a dynamic-inside-dynamic approach.   But the query to the non-existent table needs to be in its own context so the optimizer won't try to validate its existence when it doesn't exist.

**EDIT:**
The problem is that if your "IF EXISTS()" check is in the same context as your "SELECT FROM NoSuchTable" query, then the optimizer won't allow that whole statement-batch to run because it will check and see the table doesn't exist.  It doesn't matter that you can't logically get to the point of trying to select from a non-existent table.  The optimizer validates the existence of every object that is referred to in its current context before it starts running the first statement.

But, when you do IF EXISTS() THEN Run-some-dynamic-statement, then the contents of the dynamic statement aren't evaluated by the optimizer until it hits the EXECUTE(@sql) command.   And it won't ever hit that command unless IF EXISTS() is true, so it won't get evaluated at all unless the table exists.

Comment: Yes, but all this is within a case statement loop, where I run the query against a series of tables (some that may exists and some that may not). So, this is why the IF Exists is included in the dynamic sql. So, I'll try your suggested dynamic within dynamic.

Comment: dynamic within dynamic, if it's allowed, should work.   Editing my answer with more detailed explanation.

Comment: I attempted two versions of dynamic within dynamic, updated original post with examples. Both resulted in same error, that the table did not exist. When I ran those versions on a table that did exist, they worked. Appears, the object is being evaluated in all scenarios.

Comment: Your answer prompted me to direct my attention to the case loop. The thought occurred to check for the table existence after the case statement: and, set a global variable to 'Yes' or 'No' (using a global variable user stored procedure). Next, check for the global variables state, if yes, run dynamic query, if no, then go to next in loop. Basically, pulling out the IF Exists from the dynamic qry and utilizing a global variable.

Comment: The only response to that I can offer is, it depends on how the "case loop" is set up.  If it's set-based, then the global variable isn't going to be evaluated separately for each row in the set.   If it's in a while loop, with only one possible case each time, then it might work.

Comment: See my comment on your question regarding your dynamic-within-dynamic attempts.   Did you try my exact code as a test?   Although mine isn't dynamic-within-dynamic....

Comment: Yes, the code you provided works. But, for my application, I need to dynamically loop through the IF EXISTS with a series of table names (...WHERE name = N''' +@sometable+'''). This is part of the case-loop. The global variable approach worked.